# Why is converting from int to char* different from converting from std::string to char*?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I'm learning C++ and reading Andrei Alexandrescu's book on generic programming. He presents a templated class that can be used to convert between types:

```
template <class To, class From>
To safe_reinterpret_cast(From from)
{
    assert(sizeof(From) <= sizeof(To));
    return reinterpret_cast<To>(from);
}
```

This works fine for:

```
int i = 5;
char* p = safe_reinterpret_cast<char*>(i);
```

but fails for

```
std::string a("apple");
char* pp = safe_reinterpret_cast<char*>(a);
```

This is the error failure at compile time:

```
invalid cast from type 'std::basic_string<char>' to type 'char*'
```

Why does this cast fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrei Alexandrescu's infamous example only works for plain-old-data types.

It does **not** work for pointers. The behaviour of casting unrelated pointer types is undefined.

You can **only** reinterpret_cast to `void*`, and reinterpret_cast from `void*` back to the original pointer type.

Comment: I think the point here is that `std::string` is not a pointer, nor a POD.

Answer (score 1):

Because `int` and `char` are primitive types, while `std::string` is not.

Comment: so my larger question is can reinterpret_cast never be used for non-primitive types?